# Starting a new board in Carrom

Tags: carrom

In Carrom, does the winner of a board automatically start the next one? If not does the starting player, play white Carrom men?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm

Relevant rules:
`43) The player who is to break shall have the white C/m during that board leaving the black C/m to his opponent. The Queen shall be the common C/m.`

`49) a) i) In the first game the player who chooses to break the first board shall have the white C/m. The turn to break shall pass alternately during the game.`

`49) a) ii) In the second game the player who did not have the first turn to break shall have his turn first.`

`49) a) iii) In the third game, the turn to break passes on to the first player.`

Summary:
a) Whomever is breaking plays the white c/m.
b) The first break of the first game will be taken by whomever is chosen to break first.  The second board of the first game will be broken by the other player, and so on.
c) The first break of the second game will be taken by the player who did not have the first break in the first game.
d) The first break of the third game will be taken by the player who did have the first break in the first game.

Sample match can be seen here: https://youtu.be/MTLHyG5ov44

Comment: I really appreciate your support.

Your answer was clear and precise

Many thanks.

Mick W

Comment: @Pecker Happy to help!  Please select it as the answer.